# Data structure for fast range searches of dense dataset 4D vectors

Tags: c++, sql, data-structures, vector

I have millions of unstructured 3D vectors associated with arbitrary values - making for a set 4D of vectors. To make it simpler to understand: I have unixtime stamps associated with hundreds of thousands of 3D vectors. And I have many time stamps, making for a very large dataset; upwards of 30 millions vectors.

I have the need to search particular datasets of specific time stamps.

So lets say I have the **following data**:

For time stamp *1407633943*:

- (0, 24, 58, 1407633943)
- (9, 2, 59, 1407633943)

  ...

For time stamp *1407729456*:

- (40, 1, 33, 1407729456)
- (3, 5, 7, 1407729456)

  ...

etc etc

And I wish to make a very fast query along the lines of:

*Query Example 1*:

Give me vectors between:

X > 4 && X < 9 && Y > -29 && Y < 100 && Z > 0.58 && Z < 0.99

Give me list of those vectors, so I can find the timestamps.

*Query Example 2*:

Give me vectors between:

X > 4 && X < 9 && Y > -29 && Y < 100 && Z > 0.58 && Z < 0.99 && W (timestamp) = 1407729456

So far I've used SQLite for the task, but even after column indexing, the thing takes between 500ms - 7s per query. I'm looking for somewhere between 50ms-200ms per query solution.

What sort of structures or techniques can I use to speed the query up?

Thank you.

Comment: I was afraid with the title with vector 4D, I think about `vector<vector<vector<vector<T>>>>` whereas it was in fact `vector<T>` with `T` a class with 4 fields.

Answer (score 0):

kd-trees can be helpful here. Range search in a kd-tree is a well-known problem. Time complexity of one query depends on the output size, of course(in the worst case all tree will be traversed if all vectors fit). But it can work pretty fast on average.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree). In each node I would store arrays of vectors in a [hashtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) using the timestamp as a key.

To further increase the performance you can use CUDA, OpenCL, OpenACC, OpenMP and implement the algorithms to be executed in parallel on the GPU or a multi-core CPU.

Answer (score 0):

BKaun: please accept my attempt at giving you some insight into the problem at hand.  I suppose you have thought of every one of my points, but maybe seeing them here will help.

Regardless of how ingest data is presented, consider that, using the C programming language, you can reduce the storage size of the data to minimize space and search time.  You will be searching for, loading, and parsing single bits of a vector instead of, say, a SHORT INT which is 2 bytes for every entry - or a FLOAT which is much more. The object, as I understand it, is to search the given data for given values of X, Y, and Z and then find the timestamp associated with these 3 while optimizing the search.  My solution does not go into the search, but merely the data that is used in a search.

To illustrate my hints simply, I'm considering that the data consists of 4 vectors:

1. X between -2 and 7,
2. Y between 0.17 and 3.08,
3. Z between 0 and 50,
4. timestamp (many of same size - 10 digits)

To optimize, consider how many various numbers each vector can have in it:
              1. X can be only 10 numbers (include 0)
              2. Y can be 3.08 minus 0.17 = 2.91 x 100 = 291 numbers
              3. Z can be 51 numbers
              4. timestamp can be many (but in this scenario, 
                 you are not searching for a certain one)

Consider how each variable is stored as a binary:
   1. Each entry in Vector X COULD be stored in 4 bits, using the first bit=1 for 
      the negative sign:
                 7="0111"
                 6="0110"
                 5="0101"
                 4="0100"
                 3="0011"
                 2="0010"
                 1="0001"
                 0="0000"
                -1="1001"
                -2="1010"

```
     However, the original data that you are searching through may range 
        from -10 to 20!
     Therefore, adding another 2 bits gives you a table like this:  
            -10="101010"
             -9="101001" ...
             ...
             -2="100010"
             -1="100001" ...
             ...
              8="001000"
              9="001001" ...
             ...
             19="001001"
             20="010100"

    And that's only 6 bits to store each X vector entry for integers from -10 to 20
    For search purposes on a range of -10 to 20, there are 21 different X Vector entries
        possible to search through.
```

1. Each entry in Vector Y COULD be stored in 9 bits (no extra sign bit is needed)
        The 1's and 0's COULD be stored (accessed, really) in 2 parts 
            (tens place, and a 2 digit decimal).
            Part 1 can be 0, 1, 2, or 3  (4 2-place bits from "00" to "11")
                 However, if the range of the entire Y dataset is 0 to 10, 
                    part 1 can be 0, 1, ...9, 10 (which is 11 4-place bits 
                        from "0000" to "1010"
            Part 2 can be 00, 01,...98, 99 (100 7-place bits from "0000000" to "1100100"
            Total storage bits for Vector Y entries is 11 + 7 = 18 bits in the 
                range 00.00 to 10.99
     For search purposes on a range 00.00 to 10.99, there are 1089 different Y Vector 
         entries possible to search through (11x99) (?)
2. Each entry in Vector Z in the range of 0 to 50 COULD be stored in 6 bits 
          ("000000" to "110010").
          Again, the actual data range may be 7 bits long (for simplicity's sake) 
              0 to 64 ("0000000" to "1000000")

   For search purposes on a range of 0 to 64, there are 65 different Z Vector entries
          possible to search through.

---

Consider that you will be storing the data in this optimized format, in a single 
  succession of bits:

X=4 bits + 2 range bits = 6 bits
 + Y=4 bits part 1 and 7 bits part 2 = 11 bits
 + Z=7 bits

### + timestamp (10 numbers - each from 0 to 9 ("0000" to "1001") 4 bits each = 40 bits)

= TOTAL BITS: 6 + 11 + 7 + 40 = 64 stored bits for each 4D vector

---

THE SEARCH:

Input xx, yy, zz to search for in arrays X, Y and Z (which are stored in binary)
   Change xx, yy, and zz to binary bit strings per optimized format above.

function(xx, yy, zz)

```
    Search for X first, since it has 21 possible outcomes (range is -10 to 10) 
       - the lowest number of any array
    First search for positive targets (there are 8 of them and better chance 
        of finding one)
         These all start with "000" 
             7="000111"
             6="000110"
             5="000101"
             4="000100"
             3="000011"
             2="000010"
             1="000001"
             0="000000"
          So you can check if the first 3 bits = "000".  If so, you have a number
          between 0 and 7.
             Found: search for Z
                Else search for xx=-2 or -1: does X = -2="100010" or -1="100001" ? 
                  (do second because there are only 2 of them)
                     Found: Search for Z
          NotFound: next X

    Search for Z after X is Found: (Z second, since it has 65 possible outcomes 
     - range is 0 to 64)
          You are searching for 6 bits of a 7 bit binary number
               ("0000000" to "1000000")  If bits 1,2,3,4,5,6 are all "0", analyze bit 0.  
                 If it is "1" (it's 64), next Z
                     Else begin searching 6 bits ("000000" to "110010") with LSB first
                        Found: Search for Y 
                        NotFound: Next X

    Search for Y (Y last, since it has 1089 possible outcomes - range is 0.00 to 10.99)
           Search for Part 1 (decimal place) bits (you are searching for 
            "0000", "0001" or "0011" only, so use yyPt1=YPt1)
                Found: Search for Part 2 ("0000000" to "1100100") using yyPt2=YPt2 
                (direct comparison)
                    Found:  Print out X, Y, Z, and timestamp
                NotFound: Search criteria for X, Y, and Z not found in data.  
                    Print X,Y,Z,"timestamp not found". Ask for new X, Y, Z. New search.
```